# View.Gone not working for UI elements in Fragment at relaunch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am facing a peculiar problem. In my code I have a fragment with one progressbar, 2 buttons , 1 Textview. Based on some conditions I am setting the visibility of these UI elements to View.Gone or View.Visible.
The fragment is part of the main activity.When app is launched for first time, the mainactivity shows upthe fragment and the View.Gone and Visible work perfectly fine for all UI elements.  After some processing the mainactivity is relaunched and this fragment is relaunched. On the fragment relaunch the View.Gone or Visible is not working for any of the elements. I am unable to figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Some code would help. If you are setting the visibility programmatically on the views, those settings would not automatically be saved when the view hierarchy is saved and, therefore, would not be restored on the re-creation of the activity. You would have to save some indication of their state and set the values again after the activity and the fragment are restored..